# Caffeinate : prevent screensaver (Catalina)

Tags: terminal, catalina, sleep-wake, screensaver

I'm running this terminal command on Catalina hoping to keep the system awake and prevent the screensaver to start (without having to disable the screensaver in system preference).

```
caffeinate -d -i -u -s -t 39600
```

I might have added too much parameter and misunderstood them but it's don't seems to work?

Also, I assume the terminal window need to remain open?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

I probably misunderstood the parameter but without the time parameter (-t) it's seems to work fine

```
caffeinate -d -i -u -s
```

Answer (score 0):

Frame challenge…

Why not just use the Hot Corners in the Screen Saver prefs instead.

[image]

Push the cursor into the top left & no more screen saver, which will also keep the Mac awake.

Comment: Thank you, I'm aware of all the user interfaces options but I'm looking to use Caffeinate instead or any command line alternative without changing permanently the preferences files.

Comment: My company stops me using the UI settings so I'm looking to circumvent it too :)

Comment: OK I have to ask. Where did you get a Windows BSOD screensaver for your Mac?

Comment: @ADTC - it's one of hundreds I got from https://www.jwz.org/xscreensaver/ Enjoy!!

Answer (score 0):

One trick to preventing sleep and the screensaver is to run a video on a loop.  I created a small mpeg that consists of a completely black frame that is five minutes long, but any video will work.  I run it in the QuickTime Player on a loop.  It does sometimes stop if I join a video meeting or something, depends on the program -- but generally works great.

I believe Youtube in a browser window might also work -- you could open it to one of the 10 hour focus/relaxation channels for example.